# Algorithm to determine the order of shapes from top-right to bottom-left

Tags: algorithm, shapes

I have a canvas which contains N number of shapes and I'd like to assign each of them a numerical index to determine what order the shapes are in from left to right, top to bottom. I know the x/y coordinates and width/height for each shape. For my purposes, it's safe to assume that the shapes will not overlap.

Is there a known algorithm for this?

For example:
[image]

Comment: Why is 5 after 4, and not after 1? I think the order is underspecified. Its not clear which shapes should form a row.

Comment: @TamasHegedus I think this is sort of a clustering problem. 4-5 makes sense to me, but 6-7 doesn't.

Comment: @TamasHegedus I agree that 5 is ambiguous, which is why I included it in the example. It's reasonable for an algorithm to put it after 1 or after 4, depending on whether it's prioritizing horizontal ordering or vertical. One could argue that 5 should be after 4 because it overlaps more with 4 than with 1, so visually it's grouped more on the second row.